# setting desired memory address error

Tags: c, pointers, memory

```
    int *a=500;
     *a=3;
printf("%d",*a);
```

look at above code.

I want to set the address 500 of memory to 3. but when I compile this code I get an error(segmentation fault). what is the problem?

Comment: Address 500? Why 500? Also "I get an error." is as useful as "It doesn't work". Add the Error-Message please.

Comment: it is just edited

Comment: for example 500.I want to set some place in memory. why I can not?

Comment: No, you can't just pick some arbitrary number and assign it to a pointer, expecting anything good to happen.

Comment: On many systems, all the addresses on the first page (which may be as big as 4KiB) are invalid and any access will trigger a segmentation fault. You can only write to addresses assigned to your program as writable; you can’t write to read only addresses.  You chose poorly.

Comment: On most modern operating systems the address in C is not a real RAM address but a virtual address.  A process's virtual address space has a so-called "Guard Region" at the lower and upper ends of the range, and using these addresses is forbidden.  Generally the actual value of a virtual address is of no interest to the programmer (although given practice you can tell some things from an address range).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you got an exception means that you run this under an OS.
Writing to address 500 is very likely to be out of your process memory map and out of stack.

Luckily memory protection unit, does not let you write wherever you want.

Answer (score 3):

This is invalid:

```
int *a=500;
```

You can't just assign an arbitrary address to a pointer variable and expect that it is pointing anyplace useful.  You can only do something like this on embedded platforms that have well-defined addresses for specific devices.

You can only assign the address of an exiting variable or an address returned by a memory allocation function like `malloc`:

```
int b;
int *a = &b;                   // valid
int *c = malloc(sizeof(int));  // valid
int *d = 500;                  // not valid
```